# What is the difference of the Netatalk package and the Avahi package?

Tags: networking, apt, macos, nas, avahi

I am a beginner and following some online tutorials for using linux as a NAS and connecting to a mac. Nearly all tutorials talk about the need for using Netatalk and Avahi. Both seem to be networking packages, but I can't find the difference of each one. What is the difference that makes them both needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different technologies, two open source projects that implement protocols used by Apple at some point.

- **Avahi** is a project to provide support for zero configuration networking, using multicast DNS.  It isn’t just used for file sharing, but as a way to advertise network services over the local network without any specific DNS infrastructure.  You can advertise your network shares this way.  https://www.avahi.org/
- **netatalk** is an open source implementation of some AppleTalk services.  AppleTalk is a proprietary network protocol Apple included with their products, starting in the 80s.  It served a similar purpose back then to zeroconf today. Macs can advertise their AppleTalk file shares (AFP over TCP) over Bonjour (apple’s zeroconf implementation), but the protocol itself used a much older mechanism for broadcasting names and services over the local network that didn’t use IP. http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/

I don’t see much point in learning about netatalk, no modern Apple systems use AppleTalk anymore. Macs today can use SMB just fine, so just using Samba and Avahi is sufficient.

Comment: Awesome, thanks